# Javascript: can access url that returns json but when fetching, an error occurs

Tags: javascript, fetch

When I access the URL directly, I see the JSON but I am getting an error when using 'fetch' to get the data.  The error states that `uncaught v in promise`.

```
fetch('http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:157322359X&jscmd=data')
.then((resp) => {
    return resp.json()
})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: The content of your url is like 'var _OLBookInfo = { ... }'. It is not json but text. JSON must contain no 'var _OLBookInfo = '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to the following and it will work. I have just added a paramater key format with json value.

```
fetch('http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:157322359X&jscmd=data&format=json')
.then((resp) => {
    return resp.json()
})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because at the JSON endpoint you don't have pure JSON, you have JavaScript. That's why it's complaining about a 'v', because it has to be JSON.

You should just remove the `var ... =` on the endpoint